# Simplify GCD blocks and methods

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I find myself often writing **complex GCD / block based** methods (comparable to the code snippet shown below).

1. How would you **break up** this kind of method **in smaller
   portions**?
2. Would you rather GCD-enable the **parsing methods in the managed
   objects' code** or would you rather **keep** the GCD code in the **view
   controller**?
3. How can I run the **NSURL request** in the code below in the **background
   queue** (`[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` When I use `NSOperationQueue
   currentQueue`, the completion handler does not get called.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Huh? Too suggestive of what?

Comment: @skinnyTOD sorry, meant subjective... autocorrect FTL.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: ah, ok. Thought I was missing something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use a C function or a instance method to delegate certain processes (such as saving to the XML file).
2. Definitely keep it in the object's code. You are breaking MVC too much as it is,
3. Don't use `NSURLRequest`, use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) or [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) instead.

Comment: +1 for the punching line: "Use a C function (...)"

Comment: @JackyBoy Seriously, It wasn't meant as a reference to that question, I swear.

Comment: Sure... It's just in your blood man...

Comment: Why would you use RestKit instead of NSURLRequest for a rather simple request?

Comment: @AlexR because the OP asked how can I do this on the background thread, without GCD.

Comment: @Richard, isn't the `queue` parameter be meant for specifying an (background) thread?

Comment: @AlexR the queue parameter doesn't have to be another thread, in fact, it can cause problems if it is the current thread, it just says 'eventually run this code on this thread, when you can'. It gives no guarantees that the code will be called anytime this year, but generally it is ran rather quickly (within the next runloop tick).

Answer (score 2):

I would separate that so you can actually see the MVC design in it. So I would have:

1. The `UIViewController`
2. A Manager Class to handle the interactions between the `UIViewController`, the `NSURLConnection` and the XML Parser
3. A class to handle the `NSURLConnection` (or any 3rd party you would like).
4. A class to handle the XML Parsing and posterior writing.

To establish communication I would use delegation. This way you would have different blocks of work. So when you need to change the XML Parse, just switch the class; if you need to use this logic somewhere else, just switch the `UIViewController`. Keep it simple and clean.

**P.S:** Sometimes, no matter what you do, the code just is, by it's nature, complex, please use comments, you will thank yourself later...